# Error importando proyecto: "The path '..............' does not belong to a directory"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Cuando quiero importar un proyecto en Android me sale una ventana con  el siguiente error :

**The path
'C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk'
does not belong to a directory**.

**Android Studio will use this Android SDK instead:
'C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk'
and will modify the project's local.properties file.**

Cual seria la solución para que no me aparezca eso

Comment: Hola amigo esto es porque tu solo instalaste el ambiente de android studio pero este para trabajar ocupa el SDK este lo puedes descargar desde la pagina de android studio lo instalas pero recuerda donde lo guardas ya que se lo tendrás que indicar a android studio
https://developer.android.com/studio#downloads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El proyecto que tratas de cargar fue creado en otro equipo en el cual se tenía el Android SDK instalado en la ruta:

> C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

pero al tratar de cargarlo en tu PC, la configuración es diferente, en este caso tu Android SDK se encuentra instalado en la ruta:

> C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Por lo tanto **debes aceptar el cambio para que el proyecto que importas se funcione con la configuración de tu PC.**

---

Incluso puedes definir manualmente la ruta de tu Android SDK dentro del archivo `local.properties` de esta forma:

```
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\Usuario\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
```